# .net dictionary inside dictionary: adding new items to the inner dictionary

Tags: .net, vb.net, dictionary, data-structures

I have a dictionary as one of the fields of the structure of the value part of another dictionary so that a course can contain multiple classes, each with its own teacher and students as below:

```
Structure course
    Dim description As String
    Structure classs
        Dim teacherCode As String
        Dim studentIDs() As Integer
    End Structure
    Dim classes As Dictionary(Of String, classs) 'key=classCode
End Structure

Structure courseKey
    Dim name As String
    Dim yearLevel As Short
End Structure

Dim courses As New Dictionary(Of courseKey, course)
```

I can construct a courseKey and create an empty courses dictionary entry using an empty classs sub-dictionary with *courses.Add(courseKey, course)*, but I can't work out how (or, indeed, if it's possible) to create a new courses dictionary entry with a non-empty classs sub-dictionary.  I expected to be able to do something like this to create a classs and then add it to the course, but get a NullReferenceException *(even when courses(courseKey) references the appropriate dictionary item, and when classCode is a valid string and classs is a valid instance of the classs structure with data in it)*:

```
courses(courseKey).classes.Add(classCode, classs)
```

Am I missing something obvious?  I was planning on having a few data structures like this, some with multiple dictionaries inside another dictionary.  If this isn't possible, perhaps there's a better way?

Comment: What expression was null? Find out. I'm tempted to close this off as a duplicate of the canonical NRE question. I'm not seeing how this case is special.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NullReferenceException always means the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). In this case, you haven't instantiated the `classes` dictionary in your `course` structure.

```
Dim classes As Dictionary(Of String, classs) 'key=classCode
```

For comparison, you've instantiated the `courses` dictionary with the `New` keyword.

```
Dim courses As New Dictionary(Of courseKey, course)
```

Normally you would create your `classes` dictionary the same way, but in this case, it's in a `structure`, and you're not allowed to have a default constructor or member initializers in a structure.

You need to initialize your dictionary somewhere, so you have a few options. Probably the easiest would be to wrap it into a property:

```
Private _classes As Dictionary(Of String, [class])

Public ReadOnly Property Classes As Dictionary(Of String, [class])
    Get
        If _classes Is Nothing Then _classes = New Dictionary(Of String, [class])()
        Return _classes
    End Get
End Property
```

If your code is potentially multithreaded, you'd want to handle this differently, but that provides a `Classes` property on the `course` structure that will initialize its private backing member if it doesn't already exist.

(Incidentally, I changed the name `classs` to `class` and wrapped it in square brackets to escape the name.)

Answer (score 1):

Your classes dictionary inside the course class needs to be initialized. You can do this within a constructor:

```
Structure course

    ...

    Public Sub New(description As String)

        Me.description = description
        classes = New Dictionary(Of String, classs)

    End Sub

    ...

End Structure
```